# Prestashop - module - Load on each pageload

Tags: smarty, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a prestashop module

The goal of this module is that when a page on the front office is loaded a mysql query runs.
The query starts to sync the quantity's of all products.
So they match the quantity's of a external stock management system.

The code is already written, I'm only searching for the right way in prestashop to execute each time a page get loaded.

i have tried to use

```
public function hookExtraLeft($params) {
```

but this only execute the mysql query's when you are on the product page and not on the product overview.

Looking into the prestashop documentation did not help me at this moment.
(http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gskema Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
Also i want to say that I'm aware that its not a good idea to run my query's on each page view. I was planning to add an timer so it only runs a query every 30 minutes when a visitor visit a page.

using the hook footer allows met to run a sql query in order to update my stock quantity's

```
public function hookFooter($params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a query on every page view is a **very bad idea**. You should do this periodically, rather than on every view.

Go to `classes/Hook.php` @ Line 401 (PS 1.6.0.11) and add this line (justs while developing):

```
error_log($hook_name);
```

This will list all the hooks when you open a page/perform action/use ajax/etc. Hopefully you can find a suitable hook here, there are hooks which are executed on every page view.